# Algebra for the Baby

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, lie-algebras, gap

I am reading Ryba, A natural invariant algebra for the Baby Monster group, Journal of Group Theory, 2007,  https://doi.org/10.1515/JGT.2007.006
The algebra is constructed using representation theory. The formula for multiplication in the algebra is

$\bar t*\bar{t'}=\bar{t'}(t+1) + (\bar{t'},\bar{t})\bar{t} + \lambda_t(\bar{t'})$

I used bar instead of underscore for axis of transposition $t$ in $B$. The drawback of this formula is $\lambda_t$ which is constructed by use of representation theory. I would like to see direct formula for multiplication within the algebra in order to see the symmetries of baby monster. I would like to obtain algebra in GAP in which I can test some hypothesis about the algebra.

I have following questions related to this algebra.

1. Let $L$ denote $78$-dimensional simple Lie algebra generated by GAP command $SimpleLieAlgebra("E", 6, GF(2))$. What is the automorphism group of this Lie algebra - is it $^2E_6(2)$ or $E_6(2)$ ? How many generators this algebra have ? According to my test, 12 generators (basis elements 1..6 and 37..42) generate full algebra. I need to do more testing to see how to obtain subalgebra $L$ of algebra $V_{4370}$ for given transposition $t$.
2. There is $782$-dimensional subalgebra invariant for $Fi_{23}$ subgroup. This subgroup does not have any axis fixed. This subalgebra is spanned by $31671$ axes of conjugacy class $2A$ of $Fi_{23}$. Using information from chapter 6 in this paper about "dihedral subalgebras" we could define such algebra, I believe.
3. I am not sure how to define $5$-dimensional dihedral subalgebra for 4B case, because I don't follow how $l_t$ is defined in this paper.
4. From direct calculations of eigen spaces in GAP I observed that given subgroup $H$ of $B$ has vectors fixed only when stabilizer of $H$ is not trivial. This is experimental data, I don't know how to prove it.

I will add more questions when I have time to think more about it.

Comment: Whatever you do, please do not add more questions to this post. Multi-question posts should be avoided, if possible.  If you have multiple questions which can be separated, it would be much better to ask them one at a time. If two or three questions really can't be separated from each other, then it's OK to ask them at the same time.

Comment: Now (after a few weeks) posted also on MO: [Algebra for the Baby Monster group](https://mathoverflow.net/q/288338).

Comment: Exactly @MartinSleziak, thank you for adding this comment. Unfortunately I have to say that I will not get an answer on MO on this, probably.